# Property of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be an associative algebra. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Let $J$
>   be an ideal of the algebra $I$. Prove that $(J)_R$ the ideal of $R$
>   generated by elements $J$, has the property: $(J)^3_{R} \subseteq J $.

I have no idea how to prove it